# expand dataframe according to certain columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have data in the following shape:

```
old<-
data.frame(date = c("04/01/2022", "05/01/2022", "07/01/2022", "04/01/2022", "06/01/2022","07/01/2022"), 
           type = c(rep("x", 3), rep("y",3)),
           name = c("t", "p", "k", "t", "p", "L"), 
           value = c(10,20,30, 9, 5, 8))
```

I am not sure what term to use but I would like to "expand" the "old" to look like "new" dataset.

```
new <- 
  data.frame(
    date = c(rep("04/01/2022",4),rep("05/01/2022",4), rep("06/01/2022",4), rep("07/01/2022",4) ),
    type = c(rep("x", 16), rep("y", 16)), 
    name = c("t", "p", "k","L"), 
    value = c("10", "0", "0", "0", "0", "20", rep("0",8), "30" ,"0",
              "9", rep("0",8), "5", rep("0",5), "8")
  )
```

"expand" methodology is as follow:

- My data only has observations for those days where I have a value.
- I want to repeat for every day the type and name columns so that for every day I have a dataframe with all types and all names.
- for those day/type/name for which I don't have an observation in "old" then populate with 0 zero.

Note this is not a simple pivot wider since I need to add observations.

The resulting data.frame is thus an N.date x N.type x N.name matrix.

Comment: Is it a mistake that in `new` there is no `y, t, 9`? If it's a mistake, then simply `tidyr::complete(old, date, type, name, fill = list(value = 0))` should work

Comment: yes its a mistake I updated the code. Wow very easy solution could not find the function.

Comment: Are you converting the value column from numeric to character on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

## tidyr

```r
tidyr::complete(old, date, name, type, fill = list(value = 0))
# # A tibble: 32 × 4
#    date       name  type  value
#    <chr>      <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#  1 04/01/2022 k     x         0
#  2 04/01/2022 k     y         0
#  3 04/01/2022 L     x         0
#  4 04/01/2022 L     y         0
#  5 04/01/2022 p     x         0
#  6 04/01/2022 p     y         0
#  7 04/01/2022 t     x        10
#  8 04/01/2022 t     y         9
#  9 05/01/2022 k     x         0
# 10 05/01/2022 k     y         0
# # ℹ 22 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

## base R

(a little more work)

```r
do.call(expand.grid, lapply(old[,1:3], unique)) |>
  merge(old, by = c("date", "type", "name"), all.x = TRUE) |>
  transform(value = ifelse(is.na(value), 0, value))
#          date type name value
# 1  04/01/2022    x    t    10
# 2  04/01/2022    x    p     0
# 3  04/01/2022    x    k     0
# 4  04/01/2022    x    L     0
# 5  04/01/2022    y    t     9
# 6  04/01/2022    y    p     0
# 7  04/01/2022    y    k     0
# 8  04/01/2022    y    L     0
# 9  05/01/2022    x    t     0
# 10 05/01/2022    x    p    20
# 11 05/01/2022    x    k     0
# 12 05/01/2022    x    L     0
# 13 05/01/2022    y    t     0
# 14 05/01/2022    y    p     0
# 15 05/01/2022    y    k     0
# 16 05/01/2022    y    L     0
# 17 07/01/2022    x    t     0
# 18 07/01/2022    x    p     0
# 19 07/01/2022    x    k    30
# 20 07/01/2022    x    L     0
# 21 07/01/2022    y    t     0
# 22 07/01/2022    y    p     0
# 23 07/01/2022    y    k     0
# 24 07/01/2022    y    L     8
# 25 06/01/2022    x    t     0
# 26 06/01/2022    x    p     0
# 27 06/01/2022    x    k     0
# 28 06/01/2022    x    L     0
# 29 06/01/2022    y    t     0
# 30 06/01/2022    y    p     5
# 31 06/01/2022    y    k     0
# 32 06/01/2022    y    L     0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(old)
new2 <- 
  old[CJ(date, type, name, unique=TRUE), on = c("date", "type", "name")
      ][, value := nafill(value, fill = 0)][]
```

Comment: for `data.table`-complete, you can replace `replace(..)` with `nafill(value, fill=0)`

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. But I think nafill() still doesn't work directly on characters.

Comment: Good point. It worked for me because I looked at `old` without noticing the change in class (one of `old`/`new` is likely a mistake then). Thanks!